# Send data from excel to access, run queries, send query results back to excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

So basically I would like to be able to send date from excel to access, run some queries, and send the results back to excel, and do this all from excel VBA.

I would like to send my data, which is in an excel worksheet with sheet name "Enrollment Data Aggregate" to an access database H:\My file extension\Nameofdatabase.accdb and save it as a table with the name "Enrollment Data Aggregate".

I already have queries put together that run from the table "Enrollment Data Aggregate", so I think (hope) that I can delete that table, and when I pull in the new one from excel, the queries will still update. Then I would like access to run/update the queries and export them as separate tabs to my excel file.

Ideally, I would then like to continue doing other things in excel VBA. In other words, I'm really hoping that I can control all of this from excel. I have plenty of experience with excel and access, but I've only done about 4 VBA projects that were large like this (I've done lots of small macros) so I'm not super experienced. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My suggestion is to start doing this. VBA plays just as nicely with Access as Excel. Start coding it and come back here with questions. This is very open ended and seems like you are asking for someone to write code for you. If you ask **specific** questions, and show that **you** have put in effort, you will get a lot more feedback.

Comment: did you try the google?

Answer (score 2):

To export data from Excel to Access:

```
Sub ADOFromExcelToAccess()
' exports data from the active worksheet to a table in an Access database
' this procedure must be edited before use
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, r As Long
    ' connect to the Access database
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
        "Data Source=C:\FolderName\DataBaseName.mdb;"
    ' open a recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "TableName", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable  
    ' all records in a table
    r = 3 ' the start row in the worksheet
    Do While Len(Range("A" & r).Formula) > 0 
    ' repeat until first empty cell in column A
        With rs
            .AddNew ' create a new record
            ' add values to each field in the record
            .Fields("FieldName1") = Range("A" & r).Value
            .Fields("FieldName2") = Range("B" & r).Value
            .Fields("FieldNameN") = Range("C" & r).Value
            ' add more fields if necessary...
            .Update ' stores the new record
        End With
        r = r + 1 ' next row
    Loop
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

To import data from Access to Excel:

```
Sub ADOImportFromAccessTable(DBFullName As String, _
    TableName As String, TargetRange As Range)
' Example: ADOImportFromAccessTable "C:\FolderName\DataBaseName.mdb", _
    "TableName", Range("C1")
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, intColIndex As Integer
    Set TargetRange = TargetRange.Cells(1, 1)
    ' open the database
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & _
        DBFullName & ";"
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
        ' open the recordset
        .Open TableName, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable 
        ' all records
        '.Open "SELECT * FROM " & TableName & _
            " WHERE [FieldName] = 'MyCriteria'", cn, , , adCmdText 
        ' filter records

        RS2WS rs, TargetRange ' write data from the recordset to the worksheet

'        ' optional approach for Excel 2000 or later (RS2WS is not necessary)
'        For intColIndex = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1 ' the field names
'            TargetRange.Offset(0, intColIndex).Value = rs.Fields(intColIndex).Name
'        Next
'        TargetRange.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs ' the recordset data

    End With
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Running an Access Query from Excel:

```
Sub CreateAndRunQuery()

    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'This macro opens the Sample.accdb database, creates and runs an SQL query (filtering
    'all the customers from Canada). Then, it copies selected fields back in the Excel sheet.
    'The code uses late binding, so no reference to external library is required.

    'Written By:    Christos Samaras
    'Date:          05/10/2013
    'Last Updated:  29/11/2014
    'E-mail:        xristos.samaras@gmail.com
    'Site:          http://www.myengineeringworld.net
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    'Declaring the necessary variables.
    Dim con         As Object
    Dim rs          As Object
    Dim AccessFile  As String
    Dim strTable    As String
    Dim SQL         As String
    Dim i           As Integer

    'Disable screen flickering.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Specify the file path of the accdb file. You can also use the full path of the file like:
    'AccessFile = "C:\Users\Christos\Desktop\Sample.accdb"
    AccessFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Sample.accdb"

    'Set the name of the table you want to retrieve the data.
    strTable = "Customers"

    On Error Resume Next
    'Create the ADODB connection object.
    Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
    'Check if the object was created.
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Connection was not created!", vbCritical, "Connection Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Open the connection.
    con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & AccessFile

    'Create the SQL statement to retrieve the data from table.
    'Get the necessary information (first name etc.) for all the Canadian customers.
    SQL = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Address, City, Phone FROM " & strTable & " WHERE COUNTRY='Canada'"

    On Error Resume Next
    'Create the ADODB recordset object.
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    'Check if the object was created.
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        'Error! Release the objects and exit.
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set con = Nothing
        'Display an error message to the user.
        MsgBox "Recordset was not created!", vbCritical, "Recordset Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Set thee cursor location.
    rs.CursorLocation = 3 'adUseClient on early  binding
    rs.CursorType = 1 'adOpenKeyset on early  binding

    'Open the recordset.
    rs.Open SQL, con

    'Check if the recordet is empty.
    If rs.EOF And rs.BOF Then
        'Close the recordet and the connection.
        rs.Close
        con.Close
        'Release the objects.
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set con = Nothing
        'Enable the screen.
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        'In case of an empty recordset display an error.
        MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset!", vbCritical, "No Records"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Copy the recordset headers.
    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Sheets("New Query").Cells(1, i + 1) = rs.Fields(i).Name
    Next i

    'Write the query values in the sheet.
    Sheets("New Query").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

    'Close the recordet and the connection.
    rs.Close
    con.Close

    'Release the objects.
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing

    'Adjust the columns' width.
    Sheets("New Query").Columns("A:E").AutoFit

    'Enable the screen.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'Inform the user that the macro was executed successfully.
    MsgBox "The Canadian customers were successfully retrieved from the '" & strTable & "' table!", vbInformation, "Done"

End Sub
```

You will find more info here.

http://www.myengineeringworld.net/2013/10/running-access-queries-from-excel-vba.html